# In Python how do I split a string into multiple integers?

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv

I'm reading a string which is always five numbers separated by a space, I want to split this up into five individual integers so that I can process them separately.

so far I have:

```
reader = csv.reader([data.data], skipinitialspace=True)
for r in reader:
    print r
```

which allows me to print the values out, how do I store them as individual integers?

Comment: Is this a csv file you're reading from or only a list of the spaced integers?

Comment: could you show the output if your above code??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do it like this. Assuming `s` is your line from `reader`.

```
>>> s='2 3 4 5 6'
>>> s.split(' ')
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'] #just split will give strings
>>> [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')] #typecasting to ints
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] #now you have ints
```

A word of caution though, I am assuming there is no other data type in the line from `reader`. Otherwise this code has potential to crash. You can of course put `try: except:` to circumvent that or use more fine-tuned parsing techniques.

**UPDATE 0:** Brilliant one liner from @Pavel Annosov - `map(int, s.split())`. [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is a nifty python in-built function which lets you map a function to any iterable.

**UPDATE 1:** Its fairly simple to see how this will work. but to make it even more clear to @user2152165

```
ints_list = []
for r in reader:
    ints_list = map(int, r.strip().split(' '))
```

`ints_list` has a list of your ints. do what you want with it...

Comment: Or simply `map(int, s.split())`.

Comment: where do I add the line [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')]? Do I replace the code I'm using entirely?

Comment: Sorry I'm a C coder, this is my first day using Python (or any high level language), thanks for the help.

Comment: thats cool. We are all hear to learn. good luck with python and if my answer has helped please upvote and/or accept my answer...

Comment: I'm getting the following error:  ints_list = map(int, r.strip().split(' '))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: can you print what `r` is? looks like `r` is a `list` object.

Comment: When I print r it prints this:  ['76 44 113 171 253 '] The numbers are my 5 values.

Comment: ok simple change - `ints_list = map(int, r[0].strip().split(' '))`. So since `r` is an array, we extract its first element and then apply the `strip` and `split` since these are string methods and would not work on a `array`. This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now :) I can't upvote your answer though because it says I need 15 reputation points.