# What I am doing wrong? Output values below an amount

Tags: python, list, valueerror

Here is the question I am working on:

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The last value of the input represents a threshold. Output all integers less than or equal to that threshold value. Do not include the threshold value in the output.

For simplicity, follow each number output by a comma, including the last one.

Ex: If the input is:

```
50 60 140 200 75 100
```

the output should be:

```
50,60,75,
```

My code is:

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(n):
    lst.append(int(input()))
threshold = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    if list[i] <= threshold:
        print(last[i],end=',')
```

I keep getting an error, and I can't seem to know why:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '50 60 140 200 75 100'
```

Comment: What do you expect, `50 60 140 200 75 100` is _not an integer!_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python how do I split a string into multiple integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314421/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-into-multiple-integers)

Comment: You're going to have to process the result of `input` first and then convert the individual numbers to `int`.

Comment: Start here `lst = list(map(int, input().split()))` and `threshold = lst[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clean way to do this:

```py
# import numbers separated with a space
n = input()
n = n.split(' ')
n = [int(x) for x in n]  # <-- converts strings to integers

# threshold is the last number
threshold = n[-1]

# get the result
result = [x for x in n if x < threshold]
print(result)
```

the result:

```
[50, 60, 75]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following expects one number. Not a list of them.

```
n = int(input())
```

Seems like you want to get a list of numbers through one/few prompts. Try something like the following:

```
n = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:]
```

So your code would look like:

```
n = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:]
lst = []
for i in range(n):
    lst.append(int(input()))
threshold = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    if list[i] <= threshold:
        print(last[i],end=',')
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-a-list-as-input-from-user/